# Ubuntu shutdown problems

Tags: 14.04, shutdown

I bought a new notebook computer and installed Ubuntu on it.
The installation process has completed successfully, but when initiating shutdown, it failed to shut down properly. It shows a blinking window with logo instead. I had to remove the battery to shutdown.

Comment: Which Ubuntu version you are using and what is the configuration of your system hardware?